# Linq query not returning anything (Syntax might be wrong)

Tags: c#

I am trying to ensure that only NOT null items are displayed in the Console.

My code is:

```
internal static void RenderViews(List<BusinessProcessFlow> businessProcessListRaw)
{
    foreach (var results in businessProcessListRaw.Where(p => p.Index == 1))
    {
        var value = businessProcessListRaw.Where(x => results.EntityStep != null);
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The result is an empty console screen.

Comment: Yes, your LINQ looks wrong (`x` isn't even used in the second Where, but we don't know enough about your domain model to suggest a fix. Unless you explain in more detail what `Index` and `EntityStep` are and why they are relevant, we can only guess. Maybe `var value = results.EntityStep; If (value != null) Console.WriteLine(value);` is what you meant?

Comment: Is it so impossible for you to put a debug point and see what's going on? I don't see this as a real question...

Answer (score 0):

You should first provide model definitions `BusinessProcessFlowfor` class for a complete answer. If we assume that your model is something like this

```
public class BusinessProcessFlow
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int Index { get; set; }
   public EntityStep EntityStep { get; set }

   public override string ToString() 
   { 
      return $"{Id} {Name}";
   }
}
```

And you want to filter all `BusinessProcessFlow` with `Index` equal to `1` and `EntityStep` not `null`, I think the query should be something like this

```
internal static void RenderViews(List<BusinessProcessFlow> businessProcessListRaw)
    {
        foreach (var result in businessProcessListRaw.Where(p => p.Index == 1 && p.EntityStep != null))
        {
                Console.WriteLine(result);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Also, the type of `result` should have a `ToString()` method override in order for the console to print the data in the format you want.

Comment: There are issues with this answer: 1) `.ToList()` is not the issue here, as you only need to iterate. 2) the question says that nothing prints in console: but if there was any value, it would at least print something like `System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereListIterator'1[BusinessProcessFlow]'`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are currently doing is effectively iterating over the same list two times, but with different rules; the first time, you're getting each item where `Index == 1`. The next time, you're getting items where `EntityStep != null`. These two are not done together however, so you're likely to get a wrong answer.

You should be able to do all of that simpler using a slightly modified linq query:

```
internal static void RenderViews(List<BusinessProcessFlow> businessProcessListRaw)
{

    var value = businessProcessListRaw
                   .Where(p => p.Index == 1 && p.EntityStep != null)
                   .ForEach(p => Console.WriteLine(p));

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid your main mistake is in this line:

```
var value = businessProcessListRaw.Where(x => results.EntityStep != null);
```

But if you say that nothing is output to the console, then most likely there is no such data in the passed collection.

You can see it here:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var businessProcessListRaw = Init();

            foreach (var results in businessProcessListRaw.Where(p => p.Index == 1))
            {
                var value = businessProcessListRaw.Where(x => results.EntityStep != null);
                Console.WriteLine(value);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static List<BusinessProcessFlow> Init()
        {
            return new List<BusinessProcessFlow>
            {
                new BusinessProcessFlow{Index = 1, EntityStep = new EntityStep()},
                new BusinessProcessFlow{Index = 1, EntityStep = new EntityStep()},
                new BusinessProcessFlow{Index = 2, EntityStep = new EntityStep()},
                new BusinessProcessFlow{Index = 1},
                new BusinessProcessFlow{Index = 1},
            };
        }
    }

    public class BusinessProcessFlow
    {
        public int Index { get; set; }
        public EntityStep EntityStep { get; set; }
    }

    public class EntityStep
    {
    }
```

The output to the console (wrong one):
[image]

And yes, as you have already been answered, just change the condition in the `Where` section

`p => p.Index == 1 && p.EntityStep != null`

Then your method will look like this:

```
internal static void RenderViews(List<BusinessProcessFlow> businessProcessListRaw)
{
    foreach (var results in businessProcessListRaw.Where(p => p.Index == 1 && p.EntityStep != null))
    {                
        Console.WriteLine(results);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

And output to the console:
[image]

Good luck!)

Answer (score 0):

If your mission is

> to ensure that only NOT null items are displayed in the Console.

then the following would do the job.

```
internal static void PrintNotNulls(List<BusinessProcessFlow> businessProcessListRaw)
{
    foreach( var x in businessProcessListRaw)
    {  
       if (x != null) Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

If you wish to use LINQ (the `.Where` bit) then the following should work.

```
internal static void PrintNotNulls(List<BusinessProcessFlow> businessProcessListRaw)
{
    var notNulls = businessProcessListRaw
        .Where( x => x != null);

    foreach( var x in notNulls ) 
       Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

You can modify both approaches to check for more than just null: '`x.Index == 1`' or/and '`x.EntityStep != null`'.